# Is there a way to make Virtualmin listen on a domain instead of ip+port

Tags: server, webserver, admin, virtualmin

I have created a virtualmin account to manage multiple servers instead of cPanel and after reading all of the documentation I have yet to see why my subdomain does not load under port 10000.

I'd like to have some form of control if I do plan on giving other users accounts, without having to have them use an IP which does not allow port 443.

After finishing installation they gave me my IP with port 10000
and my domain with port 10000 and the only one that loads is the IP address.

Comment: If this isn't possible would a reverse proxy work under a new virtual host conf?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. To anyone on Debian facing this issue, run a virtualhost and use a reverse proxy to load the url containing port, and disable SSL only.
You should have panel.example.com running your virtualmin control panel.

Comment: maybe a bit more details with code samples explanations to how you got this working?